# How can I show bottomnavigationbar on every phone?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to implement bottomNavigationBar together with google Maps.
But GoogleMaps takes all the space left and overrides the bottomNavigatonBar. If I define googleMaps height with "dp" or so it only works for one screensize.
Is there any way to get BottomNavigationView together with googleMaps so that they fill the screen together?

Thats my actual xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fahrplanmap">

<com.MultiSelectionSpinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getSelected"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"/>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsAnzeigeActivity" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set your fragment `height` to 0dp and set `weight` to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `RelativeLayout`

something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fahrplanmap">

    <com.MultiSelectionSpinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySpinner1"
        android:text="Check" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/getSelected"
        tools:context=".MapsAnzeigeActivity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you may try using framelayout to solve this issue
try some thing like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsAnzeigeActivity" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that it could be solved with using FrameLayout